# Text file: How to get the text between string1 & next instance of string2 and set as Batch variable?

Tags: string, variables, batch-file

I was given this code by Aacini (thanks!) but I don't know how to set which text file to search for the data.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "line=Username:Desired Information</br><br>"
set "string1=Username:"
set "string2=</br><br>"

rem Remove from beginning until string1
set "line=!line:*%string1%=!"

rem Change the string2 by a one character delimiter
set "line=!line:%string2%=|!"

rem Get the desired information
for /F "delims=|" %%a in ("%line%") do set "result=%%a"

echo Result: "%result%"
```

How would I do this?  I'm sure it's just a set textfile=inbox.txt and another line of code to make it use the %TEXTFILE% variable, but I just don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't get the rigth answer because you don't post the right question. Neither in [your original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24893621/how-to-get-the-text-between-string1-next-instance-of-string2-and-set-as-batch) nor in this one you asked for something like "How to *read a file* and get the text between two strings". Also, you should specify the details of the file and post a section that contain the desired information; otherwise a Batch solution may fail because a large number of factors.

Anyway, I created this simple data file just for testing:

```
This is a sample file
with unknown format
Previous info. Username:Desired Information</br><br>
End of file
```

And this is the solution:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "string1=Username:"
set "string2=</br><br>"

for /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr "%string1%" file.txt') do (
   rem Get the next line
   set "line=%%a"

   rem Remove from beginning until string1
   set "line=!line:*%string1%=!"

   rem Change the string2 by a one character delimiter
   set "line=!line:%string2%=|!"

   rem Get the desired information
   for /F "delims=|" %%a in ("!line!") do set "result=%%a"

   echo Result: "!result!"
)
```

Output:

```
Result: "Desired Information"
```

However, this solution is prone to fail because multiple reasons, for example:

- May the file contain exclamation marks?
- May the text that contain the desired information be split in several lines?
- May that text contain the `"|"` choosen separator?
- Do you want *all* instances of the desired information? Or just the first one? Or just the last one?

Etc...

Comment: Sorry...  It does not contain the "!" symbol or the "|" symbol :D.  There will be only one instance of the data.  There is only once instance of the data, but it's between string1 and the next instance of string2.  But, this is great!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That's because it's parsing specified variables. To read a line from a file

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=1 delims=" %%A in ("c:\somefolder\somefile.txt") do (

... put your other for loop here

)
```

See `for /?` for help. See `set /?` and `call /?` (and also `for /?` again) to see syntax details.

WHERE IS MY FORMATTING AND PREVIEW.